# How to make a result from a query with 2 vars in same column

Tags: mysql

Here's my query

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '".$_POST['username']."' AND meta_value LIKE '".$_POST['password']."'
```

The thing is that the meta_value username and the meta_value password are in 2 different rows. I need to make a query that will look for both and tell me if the vars that I look for are in those rows. So I would like the result to return 1 with a simple

```
mysql_num_rows();
```

I know this is silly and should be on the same rows with different columns but I need to work with that stupid wordpress plugins who's doing it like it want.

Comment: Just posted my answer. There is a possibility that you may get erroneous results because the `GROUP BY` might be grouping on the wrong field. If you can post your table structure and brief extract of sample data from that table, that would help others answer the question more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause in conjunction with `GROUP BY` to retrieve rows satisfying **ALL** conditions that happen across multiple rows rather than columns:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    wp_postmeta
WHERE
    meta_value IN ('$filtered_username','$filtered_password')
GROUP BY
    meta_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

Do not insert $_POST values into the query directly, that is an open call for SQL injection attacks. Because you are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions: at the bare minimum, run your $_POST variables through `mysql_real_escape_string()`. But best to use [PDO](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and its support for [prepared statements](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thanks it's working great only had to change the GROUP BY with post_id instead of meta_id but that you didn't know. Thanks !